# Checking social security numbers and business identity codes in Access 97

Tags: ms-access

In my work, I was asked to write an Access 97 program which checks whether a given social security number is valid or not. The problem is that I was unable to find any good site which gives the format of SSN's in different languages. Are there any such site or where can I find those formats? The another problem is that there are languages with different alphabets so is is possible to put for example Greek letters in Access database if my Windows is in Finnish and Access 97 is in English? Or do functions like len or mid works in different alphabets?

Also, I need an algorithm to check whether a given Business ID is valid in different languages.

Comment: I don't think that it's a very good idea to store confidential data - whose loss can open your company to various law suits and other legal implications - in Access.

Comment: @HardCode: Well, I'm just doing what my boss says. To Hans up: It has an order number and a checking number in that order. The order number has seven digits a_1a_2...a_7 and to find a checking number you compute a=2a_1+4a_2+8a_3+5a_4+10a_5+9a_6+7a_7 mod 30. If this is 0 then checking number is 0. If a>1, c.n. is 11-a. If a=1 then there is no checking number. But I'm not sure whether there are something similar number in other countries, so I asked there. Some others have already implemented the Finnish Business ID.

Comment: Sorry that I'm a non-native English speaker but it is a code that identifies the company. I found that it might be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_added_tax_identification_number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Access 97?  So last century.

SSN is an American-only program, so I don't see what Finnish has to do with it.    Digits are digits in all languages.

If you're asking what other countries do for individual or tax ID numbers, that's a different issue.

I think a design that uses data like this for primary keys is doomed to failure.  A lot of US states prohibit you from collecting SSN.  What do you do for those people?  Better to have a surrogate key and make SSN just another indexed column with a unique constraint.

Comment: I have to update some old programs and I need to check whether people has a valid id. I have already found the format of Finnish, Swedish, Lithuanian and Estonian identification numer. And boss has been said that I have to use Access 97. I'm not sure if for example Russians write their own id's in Cyrillic letters or not.